# How to describe a website's favicon using schema.org structured data?

Tags: favicon, schema.org

Is there an accepted way to represent information about a website's favicon using `https://schema.org`? I am using `image` (to list here *some* of the icon variations that I generated using [realfavicongenerator.net](https://realfavicongenerator.net)) with `https://schema.org/WebSite` in the following way:

```
<script type="application/ld+json"> 
{
  "@context": "https://schema.org",
  "@type": "WebSite",
  "url": "http://localhost:4000/",
  "name": "WebSite Name",
  "image":
  [
    "/android-chrome-512x512.png",
    "/android-chrome-192x192.png",
    "/favicon-194x194.png"
  ]
}
</script>
```

A web search led me to discover the favicon for the schema.org website, but nothing about how to convey information about a website's favicon using schema.org.

Comment: Declare the `image` using `@ImageObject` -  then use `caption` and/or `comment`. If you want to go further, add `mainEntity` to `ImageObject` and define a `Thing` pointing to a Wikipedia URL about favicons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the description of the **[logo property](https://schema.org/logo)** of Schema. As in your example, this property has:

> Values expected to be one of these types **ImageObject**

However, there is also a difference from your example:

> Used on these types **Brand** **Organization** **Place** **Product** **Service**

You can see that there is no WebSite type as specified in your example.

Additionally, you can use **[Google's guide for the logo property](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/logo)**. Here you should pay attention to the following Google requirements:

> logo URL
>
> URL of a logo that is representative of the organization.
>
> Additional image guidelines:
>
> The image must be 112x112px, at minimum. The image URL must be
> crawlable and indexable. The image file format must be **[supported by
> Google Images](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/guidelines/google-images#supported-image-formats)**.

From this info, we can conclude that Google requires a square, although this is not explicitly indicated.

Like any other image, the logo also needs to be compressed, and given the insignificant visual value, the compression can be maximum, for example, I use a 65% compression level.